# Retrieve blob field from mySQL database with MATLAB

Tags: mysql, matlab, blob

I'm accessing public mySQL database using JDBC and [mySQL java connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). exonCount is int(10), exonStarts and exonEnds are **longblob** fields.

```
javaaddpath('mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar')
host = 'genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu';
user = 'genome';
password = '';
dbName = 'hg18'; 
jdbcString = sprintf('jdbc:mysql://%s/%s', host, dbName);
jdbcDriver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver';
dbConn = database(dbName, user , password, jdbcDriver, jdbcString);
gene.Symb = 'CDKN2B';
% Check to make sure that we successfully connected
if isconnection(dbConn)
    qry = sprintf('SELECT exonCount, exonStarts, exonEnds FROM refFlat WHERE geneName=''%s''',gene.Symb);
    result = get(fetch(exec(dbConn, qry)), 'Data');
    fprintf('Connection failed: %s\n', dbConn.Message);
end
```

Here is the result:

```
result = 
    [2]    [18x1 int8]    [18x1 int8]
    [2]    [18x1 int8]    [18x1 int8]

result{1,2}'
ans =
   50   49   57   57   50   57   48   49   44   50   49   57   57   56   54   55   51   44
```

This is wrong. The length of vectors in 2nd and 3rd columns should match the numbers in the 1st column.

The 1st blob, for example, should be `[21992901; 21998673]`. How I can convert it?

---

**Update:**

Just after submitting this question I thought it might be hex representation of a string.
And it was confirmed:

```
>> char(result{1,2}')
ans =
21992901,21998673,
```

So now I need to convert all blobs hex data into numeric vectors. Still thinking to do it in a vectorized way, since number of rows can be large.

Comment: interestingly enough, in the past few days there's an active thread on CSSM about accessing DB CLOBs from Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/278869

(doesn't answer your question but might be interesting to users who stumble upon here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will convert your character data to numeric vectors for all except the first column of data in `result`, placing the results back into the appropriate cells:

```
result(:,2:end) = cellfun(@(x) str2num(char(x'))',...  %# Apply fcn to each cell
                          result(:,2:end),...          %# Input cells
                          'UniformOutput',false);      %# Output as a cell array
```

Comment: @gnovice: No, neither `str2num` or `str2double` work with comma delimiters. `str2num` returns every digit as separate number, and `str2double` just ignores commas as thousand separator.

Comment: @yuk: I fixed a small bug in the code. I forgot to transpose the initial cell contents. I was treating them as 1-by-18, when they are actually 18-by-1. It should work now.

Comment: sweet, I didn't know str2num could do that!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using textscan

```
exons = cellfun(@(x) textscan(char(x'),'%d','Delimiter',','),...
result(:,2:end),'UniformOutput',false);
```

To get a cell array for each of the two numbers, you can replace the format string by `%d,%d` and drop the `Delimiter` option.

Comment: There are 2 typos: 1) `'false'` should just be `false`. 2) The input to TEXTSCAN `x` needs to first be converted to a string with `char(x')`.

Comment: @Jonas: I just accepted gnovice's answer before seeing yours. Thanks for alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
function res = blob2num(x)
res = str2double(regexp(char(x'),'[^,]+','match')');
```

then

```
exons = cellfun(@blob2num,result(:,2:3)','UniformOutput',0)
exons = 
    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]
    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]
```

Any better solution? May be on the step of retrieving  data?