# Why type data "long blob" in mysql read as "int8" in data explorer MATLAB?

Tags: mysql, database, matlab, spring-mvc

I am trying to select data in MySQL JDBC in MATLAB. One of the columns (file_data) in the table has the type "longblob". More details of the content of the file_data is shown on the picture below.

[image: file_data content with type longblob]

The two first lines are the header, and the remain-rows are the data. Before I save this file into the database MySQL (using spring-MVC and JSP), the file is a CSV file, which has delimiters ";".

The picture below is the table of the database. You can see the type of column file_data is "longblob".

[image: table of database]

But why when I try to preview the database in database explorer in MATLAB, it should be blob, but it showed "int8". More details please look at the picture below.

[image: data explorer in matlab]

According to that, I have questions:

1. How make the file_data can be read in MATLAB as "longblob" and not "int8"?
2. if the column "file_data" already successful change to longblob, how to read it as a table, so make me possible to process the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountOfBytesx1 Int8` is equal to longblob. Int8 is the Matlab `Byte` and CountOfBytes is the number of bytes stored.
You can convert it back to a file with something like:

```
fid = fopen(file_name,'w')
fwrite(fid,file_data,'*int8')
fclose(fid)
```

Code from [matlab answers](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79409-sql-blobs-converting-it-to-fileformat-using-matlab). Where `file_name` and `file_data` are the fetched values from your query.

Alternatively, you can try one of the solutions of [Retrieve blob field from MySQL database with MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647621/retrieve-blob-field-from-mysql-database-with-matlab)

To read the CSV-Data use [csvread](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)

When you have solved your question, add the solution to your [cross post](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/411454-why-type-data-long-blob-in-mysql-read-as-int8-in-data-explorer-matlab) too.

BTW: I never used `Matlab`, but a simple websearch for `Matlab int8 longblob` guided me.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I just want to confirm your question: "Why don't you store the CSV-Data as text? Not only CSV's stored?" >> do you mean it will be better store the CSV file as varchar in MySQL, rather than save as longblob?

Comment: @AgnesPalit `VARCHAR`may be too small (about 65K max): and I thought about make the Data readable, but this can be done with the `CONVERT` function in the query, so ignore that question.

Comment: I have tried to change from "longblob" into "longtext" type. So that, when I open in MATLAB, I can easier to see the file_data as "char". But my problem now, when I want to convert the content inside file_data column into table. I hv tried `fid = fopen(file_name,'w')
fwrite(fid,file_data,'*int8')
fclose(fid)` but I got error, the file_name should be a file. In this case, the file_name I substitute as `file_name = data{2,2}`. which is the `data` is the table that I fetch from database above. And data{2,2} is file_data contain of data csv that I have convert to longtext. Any idea with this?